# While Loops in Java Problems

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, integer

Now we are learning about while loops - here is the challenge. "the program should repeatedly prompts the user to enter a number. Keep a running total of the numbers the user enters and also keep a count of the number of entries the user makes. The program should stop whenever the user enters something that is not an integer. When the user has finished, print the number of entries the user has typed and their sum."

"A sample interaction with this program might look like this:
Program: Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer value to finish. Then press return.

User: 2

Program: Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer value to finish. Then press return.

User: 6

Program: Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer value to finish. Then press return.

User: 89

Program: Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer value to finish. Then press return.

User: q

Program: You entered 3 integers. The sum of your entries is 97."

Here's what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputSequence
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer value to finish. Then press return.");
        int sum = 0;
        int total = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            scan.next();
            System.out.println ("Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer value to finish. Then press return.");
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            sum = input + input;
            total = total + 1;
        }
        System.out.println ("You entered " + total + " integers. The sum of your entries is " + sum);
    }
}
```

I'm just a bit confused because my interaction seems to skip the system.out.println every 2nd time in the while loop and then doesn't count the first input into the total. I believe the sum also doesn't always calculate correctly. Also, if I input a lot of integers then a non-integer to end the program I will receive an error rather than the end message. However, let's say I put in two integers then a string, I will get the end message.

Comment: I think I have everything I need, just in the wrong order in the while loop. I just can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the usage in `scan.next()` that can be removed and should show the `System.out.println` correctly.

`.next()` method is a generic method of `nextInt()` which returns a `String` instead.

Another thing you can do is to switch from a `while` loop to `do while` to prevent you from repeating this line twice:

```
System.out.println ("Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer value to finish. Then press return.");
```

an example would be:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int total = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println ("Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer value to finish. Then press return.");
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            sum = sum + input;
            total = total + 1;
        } while (scan.hasNextInt());
        System.out.println ("You entered " + total + " integers. The sum of your entries is " + sum);
    }
```

Comment: Great! I'll go try that now thank you

Comment: Okay so that fixed the amount of integers inputed and the system out print, however, the sum still seems to be incorrect. For context, I put in 10 then 20 then a - the program said the sum was 40

Comment: @emily `sum = input + input;` should probably be `sum = sum + input;` that is why you are getting the wrong sum.

Comment: Of course it should be ‍♀️ how silly of me, thank you!

Comment: Please note that the above example was meant for illustration purposes, there are a few edge cases that can break this logic, but it will be left to coder as an exercise :)